# Why can't I use the tag "greenhouse"?

Tags: bug

Why can I NOT use the tag 'greenhouse' x 17?  I am in the middle of putting the plastic on and I am having a few problems...A notice came up that my reputation is still below 150 and I am not able to make a NEW tag but there IS a tag on greenhouses already to select. I've tried 3X now and getting frustrated.  Help!

Answer (score 6):

The tag is [greenhouse](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse). If you start typing that word, you'll be presented with a list of tags with the same sequence of letters in their names; you can click on the one for [greenhouse](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouse) and you should be OK. If you type out the word "greenhouse" in full, you  need to hit <kbd>Space</kbd> after it for the system to accept that you've finished that tag (and are maybe moving on to the next).

As you've noticed, you need 150 rep on this site to create a new tag. The tag system will also prevent you from creating tags that are too similar to existing ones; for example, even if you had the rep, you wouldn't be able to create a tag [green-house](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-house) or [greenhouses](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greenhouses).